# bind gridview column dynamically from dynamic datatable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which I have 10 columns.Among 10 I have set of 5 columns naming as Ata,Hplan,Hosp,Other(these 4 are checkboxfield),Othercolor(Boundfield) and again Alta,Hplan and so on..Now I want on user dropdown selection either 5 columns to be added or all 10..Do I need to disable viewstate of gridview?how can I achieve this..and second question is how can I bind these columns dynamically during row databound event.Basic thing is that I want gridview column names come duplicate but in datatable I cant give duplicate column names.please help..

```
protected void Btnshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex==1)
            {
                dtgridbind.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[10] { new DataColumn("1_ALta", typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_Hplan", typeof(bool)),
                            new DataColumn("1_Hosp",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_other",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_othercolor",typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("2_ALta", typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("2_Hplan", typeof(bool)),
                            new DataColumn("2_Hosp",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("2_other",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("2_othercolor",typeof(string))});
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A", false, true, false, false, "Red");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A", false, true, false, false, "Red");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A", false, true, false, false, "Red");
                GridView1.DataSource = dtgridbind;
                GridView1.DataBind();
               // ViewState["modechange"] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dtgridbind.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("1_ALta", typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_Hplan", typeof(bool)),
                            new DataColumn("1_Hosp",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_other",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_othercolor",typeof(string))});
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "Red");
              //  ViewState["grid"] = dtgridbind;
                GridView1.DataSource = dtgridbind;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {

                foreach (DataColumn datacol in dtgridbind.Columns)
                {
                    if (datacol.ColumnName.Contains("_othercolor"))
                    {
                        BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                        bfield.HeaderText = datacol.ColumnName.Substring(2, datacol.ColumnName.Length - 2);
                        bfield.DataField = datacol.ColumnName;
                        GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        CheckBoxField ck = new CheckBoxField();
                        ck.HeaderText = datacol.ColumnName.Substring(2, datacol.ColumnName.Length - 2);
                        ck.DataField = datacol.ColumnName;
                        GridView1.Columns.Add(ck);





                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code do what you want? In this code, there is a dropdown list with two values. If the "10 Columns" is selected, it posts back and adds the 10 columns to the datatable. If the "5 Columns" is selected, it posts back and adds the 5 columns to the datatable.

In the OnRowDataBound it loops through the header cells, and splits the text based on the "_" character. It then takes the second part. This will only work if you follow this naming convention for columns.

You can't have datacolumns with the same column name. To get around this, you can use the OnRowDataBound and just alter the cell text as described above.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value =""></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="10 Columns" Value ="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="5 Columns" Value ="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private DataTable dtgridbind = new DataTable();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                foreach (TableCell headerCell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    headerCell.Text = headerCell.Text.Split('_')[1]; 
                }
            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                dtgridbind.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[10] { new DataColumn("1_ALta", typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_Hplan", typeof(bool)),
                            new DataColumn("1_Hosp",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_other",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_othercolor",typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("2_ALta", typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("2_Hplan", typeof(bool)),
                            new DataColumn("2_Hosp",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("2_other",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("2_othercolor",typeof(string))});
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A", false, true, false, false, "Red");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A", false, true, false, false, "Red");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A", false, true, false, false, "Red");
                GridView1.DataSource = dtgridbind;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                dtgridbind.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("1_ALta", typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_Hplan", typeof(bool)),
                            new DataColumn("1_Hosp",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_other",typeof(bool)),new DataColumn("1_othercolor",typeof(string))});
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "N/A");
                dtgridbind.Rows.Add(true, false, false, false, "Red");
                GridView1.DataSource = dtgridbind;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Screenshot of results:
[image]

Comment: heyyy ..thanks buddy..but Iam not getting any  text inside headercell.text.I have not defined columns statically in gridview.I really don't know why this is happening..somebody knows??

Comment: I added a screenshot of the results I am getting to the bottom of the post. Does this match what you get? The datatable is binded to the gridview, and therefore the column names will be the headercell text. When I debug the code, the headercell.text is populated with the datatable column names.